# Laravel intertia session folder size rapidly increasing to TB and site becomes down due to disk space full

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, nginx, inertiajs

I have build a website on Laravel 9, using inertia vuejs as a frontend and i am also processing SSR (Server Side Rendering) for SEO.

I have another instance for Apis and web project connects to the APIs using CURL method, same APIs are being used for mobile apps also and there is no connectivity of database in web project,

I deployed the project to production where we are using server pilot for deployment, where Nigix is used for reverse proxy and using Apache as a webserver.

The issue is /Storage/Framework/Session folder size is increasing by 1GB per minute and in result it reaches to TB and website down due to disk space full.

i have done a lot debug but unable to get the clue.

I debug the server and tried to change the session driver and didn't get any luck, i just wanted to know why this problem comes, as this is happened to me first time